# Optimization of coefficients by using genetic algorithm

Tags: optimization, genetic-algorithms

I want to optimization the coefficient of FIR filter using genetic algorithm method.

The main data structures in the Genetic Algorithm are:

chromosomes (vector)

objective function values

fitness values

If the objective function is :

[image]

and

in the passband

[image]

in the stopband

[image]

How to determine the objective function ?

Comment: The folks at Signal Processing.SE helpfully edited your question for you to provide nicer formatting: https://dsp.stackexchange.com/q/46175/5874.  It would have been nice to have preserved those improvements.  (You can click 'edit' there to see what they changed it to and learn how to use Latex on this site, then click 'edit' here to update this copy with those improvements.)

Comment: I don't understand what you are asking.  What does "how to find the objective function" mean?  It looks like you've provided us the definition of the objective function above.  So what is missing?

Comment: It seems like this question depends heavily on the components used within matlab. Specific questions about implementations in a certain language are off topic here. However, if you can ask your question without referring to specific matlab tools, it could be on topic.